# Linux cu command returns line in use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port

I have a Huawei K3765 gsm dongle connected to a usb port on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am trying to [send and receive text messages in python](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem).

I know the dongle is attached to `ttyUSB0`, `ttyUSB1` and `ttyUSB2` since that is what calling `dmesg | grep tty` tells me

`ttyUSB0` seems to be working perfectly if I run `cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0` the output is `Connected.` and I can execute commands. This makes sense because `/dev/ttyUB0` also works in the [python software](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem).

I have changed permissions of `dev/ttyUSB2` with the command `chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB2`. `ttyUSB1` and `ttyUSB2` do not seem to be functioning, if I run the same command `cu -l /dev/ttyUSB2` the output is 
`cu: /dev/ttyUSB2: Line in use`

How is it possible that `cu` says the line is in use but both `ps` and `lsof` return nothing using that line?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the use by running `sudo lsof | grep tty`  from there i saw there was a process running on `/dev/ttyUSB2` once i killed that process `sudo kill <PID>` I was able to connect to `/dev/ttyUSB2`

The first time I didn't run `lsof` as the super user so I didn't see all the processes running.